# The value of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{{x\sin 2x}}{{\left( {1 + \pi {{\sin }^2}x} \right)\left( {1 + 2\pi {{\sin }^2}x} \right)}}} dx$$

Comment: Do you only need the answer, or the way to the answer?

Comment: @JanEerland It would be better to show all the way despite mr.dang hasn't asked about it. I think also the community would benefit.

Comment: $$\int {\frac{{x\sin 2x}}{{\left( {1 + \pi {{\sin }^2}x} \right)\left( {1 + 2\pi {{\sin }^2}x} \right)}}} dx$$


$$=x\int\dfrac{\sin2x\ dx}{(1+\pi\sin^2x)(1+2\pi\sin^2x)}-\int\left[\dfrac{dx}{dx}\int\dfrac{\sin2x\ dx}{(1+\pi\sin^2x)(1+2\pi\sin^2x)}\right]dx$$


For $\int\dfrac{\sin2x\ dx}{(1+\pi\sin^2x)(1+2\pi\sin^2x)}$

set $\sin^2x=u$

Comment: more detailed you make it?

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\frac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\pi}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\pi}}}$$